# Can't subscribe to Pusher channel using nodejs

Tags: node.js, pusher

I'm trying to use the Pusher nodejs module to subscribe to Bitstamp's live orderbook feed.

```
var Pusher = require('pusher');
var pusher = new Pusher('de504dc5763aeef9ff52');
var order_book_channel = pusher.subscribe('order_book')
```

Nodejs replies with:

```
TypeError: Object #<Pusher> has no method 'subscribe'
```

Not too sure where the problem lies, any help would be appreciated.

Kind regards,
Christian

Comment: Are you sure there is a subscribe method? I don't see it in the doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pusher

Comment: You're right, I needed the pusher-client module instead. Thanks didn't realise there were more than one :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of pusher library, require the pusher-client library.

From there on proceed as normal..

```
var Pusher = require('pusher-client');
var pusher = new Pusher('de504dc5763aeef9ff52');
var order_book_channel = pusher.subscribe('order_book');
order_book_channel.bind('data', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
```

Comment: When your app is not hosted in Pusher default servers, for me it's europe, then you need to tell your cluster `var pusher = new Pusher('APP_KEY',{ cluster: 'eu' });`